# Zend 1.11.X Framework Multiple Wheres?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is it possible to use the Zend_Db_Select where/whereOr in such a way where I can do:

```
$select->whereOr('field1 = ? field2 = ?', array($value1, $value2));
or
$select->whereOr('field1 = ? field2 = ?', $value1, $value2);
```

This would be a lot easier than having to remember to escape the variables myself.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the situation, like if you have two conditions and each one has an OR within it.

like:

```
WHERE (col = $someValue OR col = $otherValue) OR (col2 = $thirdValue AND col2 = $fourthValue)
```

Those would have to be done manually.  I like to do it like this:

```
$orWhere = array(
    "(col = {$someValue} OR col = {$otherValue})",
    "(col2 = {$thirdValue} AND col2 = {$fourthValue})"
);

$select->where(implode(' OR ', $orWhere));
```

That's been a nice useful work around for me in those situations because of how Zend_Db_Select behaves it encapsulates each `where()` and `orWhere()` in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$select->where('field1 = ?', $value1)->orWhere('field2 = ?', $value2);
```